# How to use ipcRender inside executeJavascript?

Tags: electron

I tried just simply putting the ipcRenderer message inside of executeJavascript but it returned

> ipcRenderer is not defined

my ipcRender is defined using window.ipcRenderer:

```
const { ipcRenderer, remote } = require('electron');
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer;

//and then

remote.getCurrentWebContents().executeJavaScript(`settingsDiv.addEventListener('click', function() { ipcRenderer.send('test','ayy'); } );`)
```

This is loaded as a preloaded script for a webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to take that path on a preload.

Something like this should work instead:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
   const settingsDiv = document.querySelector('<?>');  // replace <?> with your selector for that div element
   settingsDiv.addEventListener('click', () => { 
         ipcRenderer.send('test', 'ayy'); 
   });
}
```

(the preload runs first, then the page is rendered. So we have to wait until the DOM content is loaded and the div is available)